# PHP Serialize a SplPriorityQueue

Tags: php, spl

today i had a issue with SplPriorityQueue.. i wanted to cache the Queue, but my cache was empty the whole time. After more then one hour to find the problem in my code ... i saw that i got an empty string when i serialize the SplPriorityQueue.

can someone here explain me why this is happen i thought the Queue is a simple Object?

```
  $institutionList = new SplPriorityQueue();

    foreach ($institutions as $institution) {

        $institution->currentPriority = 0;

        $institution->currentPriority += 2 * $this->diffSearchString($searchStrings, $institution->title);

        $institution->currentPriority += $this->diffSearchString($searchStrings, $institution->shortDescription);

        $institution->currentPriority += $this->diffSearchString($searchStrings, $institution->measures);

        $institution->currentPriority += $this->diffSearchString($searchStrings, $institution->personGroups);

        $institution->currentPriority += $this->diffSearchString($searchStrings, $institution->regions);

        $institution->currentPriority += $this->diffSearchString($searchStrings, $institution->tags);

        if ($institution->currentPriority > 0) {
            $institutionList->insert($institution->id, $institution->currentPriority);
        }
    }
     $test =  serialize($institutionList);
```

Comment: `unsserialize($test)`? And no errors??

Comment: WHat does `$this->diffSearchString()` do?

Comment: is `$institutions` instantiated elsewhere? as you are creating an instance of SplPriorityQueue in the variable `$institutionList`

Comment: `$test =  serialize($institutions);` is not serializing your Queue

Comment: the  $institutionList is not empty .. when i vardump it a can see the spl object